# How to represent "Drawable" of X11 in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am using a 3rd party library in Qt. with an API,i need to pass the "Drawable" object to it . Its mentioned the drawable is an X Windows Pixmap and is assumed to exist on X Screen screen of Display display

In this case i need to use a Qt pixmap to pass to it as drawable . How do i accomplish this. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the docs can help you: [Qt::HANDLE QPixmap::x11PictureHandle () const](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qpixmap.html#x11PictureHandle)

Comment: when i pass the Qpixmap::X11PictureHandle it shows an error on execution       X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Major opcode: 3 (X_GetWindowAttributes)
  Resource id:  0x2e0000f ...